# How to serialize XML datatype/format on C# ASP.Net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, odata, xml-serialization

I'm having a problem getting the XML datatype from the API with OData Query, when I use OData Query to get the XML datatype or format it gives me an **ERROR**

> InvalidDataContractException: Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectSome`1[OData_Web_API.Models.User]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

But without the OData Query on the API, everything is fine.

**Model**

```
    // <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
    #nullable disable
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    namespace OData_Web_API.Models
    {
        [DataContract]
        public partial class User
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public Guid? UserGuid { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Username { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Comment { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool IsOnLine { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? LastLockedOutDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int? FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int? FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool SaasAdmin { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int? DefaultIscinstanceId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool TouAgreed { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? TouDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int ProfileId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool IsDel { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime ModTime { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int ModId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string MaidenName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int PrefFirstView { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int PrefFirstWidth { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool SurveyAdmin { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int? PrimOrgId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool AllowExtAuth { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string TcuserId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool UseUi2020 { get; set; }

            public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    // GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet("get.{format}"), FormatFilter]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
      if (_context.Users == null)
      {
          return (IEnumerable<User>)NotFound();
      }
        return _context.Users;
    }
```

**This is the API that works without OData Query**

```
https://localhost:7125/api/Users/get.xml
```

**And this is the API that has an OData Query that don't work and gives me the ERROR**

```
https://localhost:7125/api/Users/get.xml?$select=UserId
```

Hoping anyone could help, been stuck in this Error for almost a week

Comment: what do you mean **look like** @GertArnold?

Comment: it is the **Controller** code that shows `User` @GertArnold

Comment: oh, just ignore `UserProfile` its still an error

Comment: even if you delete the `UserProfile` the error still occur @GertArnold

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value#enabling-expand-and-select

Comment: that is basically for ASP.NET 4.x, I'm using the .NET 6 cause they provide long term support @GertArnold

Comment: Yeah, but to use `$select` you have to meet some requirements.

Comment: yup! cause I used OData in it @GertArnold

Comment: I have to use select cause there is an OData integration in the API @GertArnold

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message says, you can try to add the public parameterless constructor to your User class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: then what is inside `public User(){...}` ?

Comment: It can be empty. The deserialization behavior just depends on the presence of the public parameterless constructor.

Comment: still the same error occurs