# How to Create Data or Entity Relationship on the same Table and Join another Table on the first Joined Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem building data or entity relationships with the same table and joining another table to the first inner joined table.

**I want to get the query result this way:**

```
SELECT [n].[ISCInstanceId], [n].[NavPointId], [n].[ParentNPId], [n].[DataPointId], [n].[NodeOrder], [n].[RefNumber], [n].[TreeTitle], [n].[IsArchived], [n].[IsInNavbar], [i].[Name]
  FROM [NavPoints] AS [n]
  INNER JOIN [NavPoints] AS [n0] ON [n].[ParentNPId] = [n0].[NavPointId]
  INNER JOIN [ISCInstances] AS [i] ON [n0].[ISCInstanceId] = [i].[ISCInstanceId]
  WHERE (([n].[IsArchived] = CAST(0 AS bit)) AND ([n].[IsInNavbar] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([n0].[ISCInstanceId] = @__IscinstanceId_0)
  ORDER BY [n].[ParentNPId], [n].[NodeOrder]
```

**but I'm getting this:**

```
SELECT [n].[ISCInstanceId], [n].[NavPointId], [n].[ParentNPId], [n].[DataPointId], [n].[NodeOrder], [n].[RefNumber], [n].[TreeTitle], [n].[IsArchived], [n].[IsInNavbar], [i].[Name]
  FROM [NavPoints] AS [n]
  INNER JOIN [NavPoints] AS [n0] ON [n].[ParentNPId] = [n0].[NavPointId]
  INNER JOIN [ISCInstances] AS [i] ON [n].[ISCInstanceId] = [i].[ISCInstanceId]
  WHERE (([n].[IsArchived] = CAST(0 AS bit)) AND ([n].[IsInNavbar] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([n0].[ISCInstanceId] = @__IscinstanceId_0)
  ORDER BY [n].[ParentNPId], [n].[NodeOrder]
```

The problem is that section or line **INNER JOIN [ISCInstances] AS [i] ON [n].[ISCInstanceId] = [i].[ISCInstanceId]** witch is the query I'm getting is not joining to the first inner joined table, I want it to be like this **INNER JOIN [ISCInstances] AS [i] ON [n0].[ISCInstanceId] = [i].[ISCInstanceId]**

**DB Context**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NavPoint>(entity =>
{
    ...
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Iscinstances)
        .WithMany(p => p.NavPoints)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IscinstanceId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_NavPoints_Iscinstances");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.NavPointsParent)
        .WithMany(p => p.NavPoints)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentNpid)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_NavPoints_NavPoints");
});
```

**Class Model**

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Odysseus_API.Models
{
    public partial class NavPoint
    {
        public NavPoint()
        {
            NavPoints = new HashSet<NavPoint>();
        }
        [key]
        public int NavPointId { get; set; }
        public int ParentNpid { get; set; }
        ...
        [ForeignKey("ParentNpid")]
        public virtual NavPoint NavPointsParent { get; set; }
        public virtual Iscinstance Iscinstances { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NavPointId")]
        public virtual ICollection<NavPoint> NavPoints { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<NavPoint>> GetNavPoint(int IscinstanceId)
{
    if (_context.Users == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var navpoint = await _context.NavPoints
               .Where(c => c.IsArchived == false  && c.IsInNavbar == true && c.NavPointsParent.IscinstanceId == IscinstanceId)
               .Include(c => c.NavPointsParent).Include(c => c.Iscinstances)
               .OrderBy(c => c.ParentNpid).ThenBy(c => c.NodeOrder)
               .Select(c => new NavPoint
               {
                   ...
               })
               .ToListAsync();

    if (navpoint == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(navpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have is:

```cs
var navpoint = await _context.NavPoints
    .Include(c => c.NavPointsParent)
    .Include(c => c.Iscinstances)
```

`Include` always applies to the root of the query, so you include the `Iscinstances` of `_context.NavPoints`. This would have the same effect:

```cs
var navpoint = await _context.NavPoints
    .Include(c => c.Iscinstances)
    .Include(c => c.NavPointsParent)
```

To `Include` the `Iscinstances` of `NavPointsParent`, use:

```cs
var navpoint = await _context.NavPoints
    .Include(c => c.NavPointsParent)
        .ThenInclude(c => c.Iscinstances)
```

`ThenInclude` expands a previous `Include`.

After your comments: the point here is that you need the navigation property `c.NavPointsParent.Iscinstance`, even when not using `Include`.

Comment: I already tried that but just the same with Include query output

Comment: `ThenInclude` is not working if I use it on the same table joined, it only joins the selected table, but I don't have a problem using it on a different table join

Comment: OK, I'll try to look into it. Time is limited...

Comment: When I reproduce your code I get `INNER JOIN [Iscinstance] AS [i] ON [n0].[IscinstanceId] = [i].[ID]` with `ThenInclude`. I had to complete your code though, like adding `IscinstanceId` to `NavPoint`. To make sure we're on the same page you should turn your question into a [mre].

Comment: okay, thanks Gert, still have this problem, really appreciate your time and effort helping out

Comment: oh I see now the problem, it is on the **Select** method actually, you have to select the `Iscinstance` data by `NavPointsParent` like for example `IscinstanceId = c.NavPointsParent.Iscinstance.IscinstanceId`

Comment: I just missed this part sorry, I should have included the `Select` method data on the code that I provided, I was too focused on the `Include` or `ThenInclude` method, but you also have to use the `ThenIncude` on the `Iscinstance` to Inner Join it on `NavPointsParent`

Comment: If there is a projection (`Select - new`) you don't need `Include`. Anyway, the point here was that you need the navigation property `c.NavPointsParent.Iscinstance`, which `ThenInclude` also does when there's no projection.

Comment: I have to use `Select` actually because I'm retrieving only selected data in both JSON on XML datatype using the `[HttpGet("get.{format}"), FormatFilter]` because there are too many columns on every tables and if I have to use OData there is a problem retrieving XML datatype and the filter will be to long

Comment: perhaps you can help me with this problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319871/how-to-serialize-xml-datatype-format-on-c-sharp-asp-net-web-api)